# how to read txt file and upload in database using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a txt file file.txt with content 'hello, this is the test file'. I need to read this file and insert the content in database using php. 
I tried following::

```
    $var = file_get_contents('file.txt', true);

    $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `mytable`.`json_dump` (`json`) VALUES ('$var')",                $con);
if ($result) {
    echo 'successful';
} else {
    echo 'got error';
}
```

But it displays got error. How to fix it??

Comment: Add this to the Error message: `echo 'got error: '.mysql_error();`. What is the output of this?
BTW, don't use mysql_* functions in new code, they are deprecated. Use MySQLi or PDO prepared statements instead.

Comment: You probably simply need to `$var = addslashes($var)` or `$var = mysql_real_escape_string($var)` first. Try spitting out the `mysql_error()` and see what it says.

Comment: got error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '\'hello, this is the test file\')' at line 1

Comment: Can you show us the exact contents of `file.txt` Does it say `hello, this is the test file` or does it say `'hello, this is the test file'` with quotes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your SQL query: `'INSERT INTO hitchernet.json_dump (json) VALUES ("' . mysql_real_escape_string($var) . '")'`

Comment: How do you know that his tablename isn't `hitchernet.json_dump`?

Comment: So, now you are inserting a string, but not enclosing it in quotes. That won't work.

Comment: Right. Now it should. But this is a bad way to do it. `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated. Better to use `mysqli` class from the beginning.

Comment: No. This won't work. You have to enclose `$var` in quotes. Yes, he should be using the newer functions, but obviously he is a beginner to PHP.

Comment: @crush It is enclosed. `\"$var\"`

Comment: I think you can fix your problem yourself if I read your way of commenting here.

Comment: `VALUES ($var)` is what you have in your answer.

Comment: @TsarIoann Okay, sorry. SO usually automatically updates answers when edits are made, and it didn't do that. While this works in this particular case, because the OP used single quotes in his file, if he had a double quote in his file, it would fail.

Comment: More universal way: `'INSERT INTO hitchernet.json_dump (json) VALUES ("' . mysql_real_escape_string($var) . '")'`. But I'm still worried that `mysql_real_escape_string` is deprecated.

Comment: The entire `mysql_*` library is deprecated. That doesn't mean it doesn't work. This last peice you commented would work, though, I'd suggest putting the `mysql_real_escape_string($var)` before the query, and sticking with the `INSERT INTO hitchernet.json_dump (json) VALUES ('$var')` because that is perfectly acceptable if `$var` is escaped properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your Query should look like this:

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `hitchernet`.`json_dump` (`json`) VALUES ('".$var."')",                $con);
```

This works fine for me so it will probably work for you to.

Comment: got error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'hello, this is the test file'')' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

The error may due to comma after hello in 'hello, this is the test file'.,Try   [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

```
 $var = mysqli_real_escape_string(file_get_contents('file.txt', true));

  $result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `hitchernet`.`json_dump` (`json`) VALUES ('$var')",                $con);
 if ($result) {
  echo 'successful';
 } else {
    echo 'got error';
 }
```

Comment: It's not due to the comma.

Comment: Let the OP look at the answers on his own. don't blame people that they don't know php...

Comment: @KeesSonnema If you don't know PHP, you shouldn't be answering on a PHP question. Period.

Comment: So all the people who have answered here don't know PHP? people are just trying to help.

Comment: @KeesSonnema,We are not expert,But we try to help someone

Comment: @KeesSonnema Just throwing out wild, ignorant answers isn't helping anyone. It's only misguiding them.

Comment: @KeesSonnema,If you know the answer,Then post it

Comment: @crush If you post on almost every answer that it will not work without any explanation why it won't work according to you you are also not really contributing anything.

Comment: @crush on this answer you said it is not due to the comma, (why not? explain?) and on my answer you said it is the same as something else (which it is not because I tested that). So if you just say something of which you are not sure of it isn't really helping either.

Comment: @Daanvn I never said that shin's answer wouldn't work. In fact, I upvoted shin's answer. I just said that it's not due to there being a comma in the text. And yes, `"some text '$var' some more text"` is the same as `"some text '" . $var . "' some more text"`

Comment: @shin that's what I've said. But crush said to me. Do you even know PHP? I don't think that's a nice way of saying that my answer is not right.

Comment: @KeesSonnema The answer you posted did not demonstrate even the most basic knowledge of PHP string concatenation. Nonetheless, I removed the "Do you even know PHP?" remark almost immediately because I felt that it was unnecessary.

Comment: @KeesSonnema,Anyway he got a solution,

Comment: can we stop this topic?.he got an answer

Comment: You need to remember that this site isn't just about getting an answer to the person asking the question. This is a Q&A site, and others are going to come to this question eventually, read it, and try to draw conclusions from it. That is why it is not acceptable to just throw out wild shots in the dark, and portray them as "possible answers".

Answer (score 1):

```
 $var = mysql_real_escape_string(file_get_contents('file.txt', true));

$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `hitchernet`.`json_dump` (`json`) VALUES ('$var')") or die(mysql_error());

if ($result) {
    echo 'successful';
} else {
    echo 'got error';
}
```